# How to monitor performance of servers on a different domain using Perfmon in Windows 7

Tags: performance-monitoring, perfmon, windows-7

We just upgraded our developer machines from 32 bit Windows XP to 64 bit Windows 7 Ultimate. With Windows XP we were able to do a live monitor of the CPU usage of servers that resided on a separate domain from our developer machines. We would use the following NET USE command to get authenticated to those servers.

NET USE *server_ip* /USER:*domain\user_name* *password*

Unfortunately we are unable to get Perfmon in combination with NET USE to work through Windows 7. The servers we are trying to monitor are running Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows Server 2003. We receive the following error when trying to connect to these servers.

Unable to connect to machine

Does anyone know how to monitor the CPU usage of remote machines on different domains through Perfmon in Windows 7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key was to use the runas command in an elevated permissions command prompt using a login associated with the domain where the servers I want to monitor reside. The command is as follows:

**runas /netonly /user:domain\username "mmc"**

I run mmc and add the perfmon snap in rather than running perfmon so I can save my settings (I am pretty disapointed this can't be done directly through perfmon). After I have my settings saved I use this command to open those settings:

**runas /netonly /user:domain\username "mmc \somepath\savesettings.msc"**